# How to generate large csv with random data using java

Tags: java

How can I generate million row records in a csv format using java with some unique data.

Comment: And any particular reason to use Java?

Comment: Have you tried anything?  You'd probably want to loop over each row, then loop over each column in each row, and generate the data

Comment: @kali, please provide more details about the scenario you are facing. Both technical details and business-needs details. You will get a better answer.

Comment: incremente a `long` variable and insert it into a new row... If you want unicity, this would be enough. If you want more type, just use a default string concateneted with that numeric like `string_val_1`, `string_val_2`, ....

Answer (score 1):

Check out [this tutorial](https://www.mockneat.com/tutorial/#csv).

The code can be quite simple:

```
MockNeat m = MockNeat.threadLocal();
final Path path = Paths.get("./test.csv");

m.fmt("#{id},#{first},#{last},#{email},#{salary}")
 .param("id", m.longSeq())
 .param("first", m.names().first())
 .param("last", m.names().last())
 .param("email", m.emails())
 .param("salary", m.money().locale(GERMANY).range(2000, 5000))
 .list(1000)
 .consume(list -> {
            try { Files.write(path, list, CREATE, WRITE); }
            catch (IOException e) { e.printStackTrace(); }
 });
```

And the possible result is:

```
0,Ailene,Greener,auldsoutache@gmx.com,4.995,59 €
1,Yung,Skovira,sereglady@mail.com,2.850,23 €
2,Shanelle,Hevia,topslawton@mac.com,2.980,19 €
3,Venice,Lepe,sagelyshroud@mail.com,4.611,83 €
4,Mi,Repko,nonedings@email.com,3.811,38 €
5,Leonie,Slomski,plumpcreola@aol.com,4.584,28 €
6,Elisabeth,Blasl,swartjeni@mail.com,2.839,69 €
7,Ernestine,Syphard,prestoshod@aol.com,3.471,93 €
8,Honey,Winfrey,pseudpatria@email.com,4.276,56 €
9,Dian,Holecek,primbra@att.net,3.643,66 €
10,Mitchell,Lawer,lessjoellen@yahoo.com,3.260,92 €
11,Kayla,Labbee,hobnailmastella@mail.com,2.504,99 €
12,Jann,Grafenstein,douremile@verizon.net,4.535,70 €
13,Shaunna,Uknown,taughtclifton@gmx.com,3.028,81 €
...
```

Answer (score 0):

This can give you an idea of how to build a generator.
The random data can be generated using Random class and adapting it to the data you need to generate.

```
public interface ICsvRandomRenerator{
  /* Adds the field definition to an array list that describes the csv */
  public void addFieldDefinition(FieldDefinition fieldDefinition);

  /* Runs a loop for the number of records needed and for each one it
     goes through the FieldDefinition ArrayList, generates the random
     data based on field definition, and adds it to the curret
     record. Last field changes to a new record*/

  public void generateFile(String fileName);
};

public class FieldDefinition(){
    String fieldName;
    String fieldType; //Alphabetic, Number, Date, etc..
    int length;
    <getters and setters>
}

public abstract class CsvRandomGenerator implements ICsvRandomGenerator{
    ArrayList<FieldDefinition> fields = new ArrayList<>();

    <@Override interface classes to implement them >.

    private String generateRandomAlpha();

    private String generateRandomDate();

    private String generateRandomNumber();

    ...
}
```